# tfs source control isn't putting project into source control

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, project

I have the project gmock and am trying to put it into my solution which is in a tfs source control.  The project file is in a subdirectory, but when I put it in as a shelveset, and then try and unshelve it, it fails to generate the subdirectory and thus doesn't have a project.

Any idea why this is happening and how to get around this?

Comment: is the new project shown in your pending changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add all of the gmock test framework to the project's tf source control, I went to the command line for Visual Studio.  Link from the start page are:

1. `VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`
2. `VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt`
3. `VS2013 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt`
4. `VS2013 ARM Cross Tools Command Prompt`

or run a cmd prompt and run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"` with one of the following parameters: `amd64`|`x86`|`x86_amd64`|`x86_arm`

This will call the appropriate `vcvars*.bat` file which will setup the correct path which will include the `tf.exe` file.

Then I went to the directory that I wanted to add and typed:

```
tf add . /recursive
```

I initially thought that this would add it to the repository, but it just marks it to be added like in git.

And that's it.  Now I can shelve my solution and have it recover elsewhere intact.

Answer (score 0):

Test pass with my enviroment (TFS2015 VS2015). Which step you got different result with me

Step1: Add new project 'Consolepzz'  in the test subfolder

[image]

Step2: Put the project in a shelveset aaa (you'd better to check the "Preserve Pending changes locally")

[image]

Step3: Unshelve the changes (Don't select undo all in the actions)

[image]

Step4: Finally found your project in the pending changes and check in it. Double check it in the solution Explorer. The project should added under the solution in source control.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work as the project that gmock has doesn't contain everything.  It has Make files python scripts, etc.  All of which I want to be included in the system.